# How to print attributes from a class?

Tags: java

(for the record I'm still new to programming)So for one of my CS class we have this project and part of it is having to print out the attributes for a class and I'm having trouble doing it? would really appreciate the help I'm pretty sure its probably simple but Ive been struggling with it for a while

```
public class Product {
private int ProductId;
private String Description;
private double Price;

public Product(int pID, String description, double price) {

    ProductId = pID;
    Description = description;
    Price = price;


}

public int getProductID() {
    return this.ProductId;

}

public void setProductID(int input) {   
    this.ProductId = input;
}



public String getDescription() {

    return this.Description;
}

public void setDescription(String DescriptionInput) {
    this.Description  = DescriptionInput;
}




public double getPrice() {
    return this.Price;
}

public void setPrice(double priceInput) {
    this.Price = priceInput;
}
```

}

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Try searching before posting! This question has definitely been asked before.

Comment: Check out `System.out.println()` in the Java API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the toString method for you.

```
public class Product {
    private int ProductId;
    private String Description;
    private double Price;

public Product(int pID, String description, double price) {

    ProductId = pID;
    Description = description;
    Price = price;


}

public int getProductID() {
    return this.ProductId;

}

public void setProductID(int input) {   
    this.ProductId = input;
}



public String getDescription() {

    return this.Description;
}

public void setDescription(String DescriptionInput) {
    this.Description  = DescriptionInput;
}




public double getPrice() {
    return this.Price;
}

public void setPrice(double priceInput) {
    this.Price = priceInput;
}

public String toString(){
  return "Product Id: "+ this.ProductId + "Description: " + this.Description + " Price: " + this.Price;
}
```

}

Finally, just invoke the toString method wherever you want to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a toString() method, so you'll be able to do this `System.out.println(Product);`